# Cannot push to array result from mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

this my code

```
  var nbu = req.body.nbu;
  var inv=[];
    db.query(
      "SELECT * FROM `invoice_ska` WHERE nm_client =?",
      nbu,
      (err, results) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        inv.push(results);
      }
    );
  }
  console.log(inv);//this just []
});
```

i cant console.log(myArr) idon`t know why

Comment: it think its because of asynchronous behaviour of node Use Promises instead of call back and await until db return data

Answer (score 0):

It's an asynchronous issue, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) complete guide from MDN explains asynchronous javascript very well.

To briefly answer your case, you will need to `console.log` the results within the query callback block. Why? Because you need to wait for the DB query to finish and return data, this happens asynchronously.

```
var nbu = req.body.nbu;
var inv=[];

db.query(
  "SELECT * FROM `invoice_ska` WHERE nm_client =?",
  nbu,
  (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    inv.push(results);
    console.log(inv);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have to code like this use async await to wait for promise and then perform ur logic

```
const someFunc = async (req, res) => {
var nbu = req.body.nbu;
var inv = [];
let results = await db.query(
    "SELECT * FROM `invoice_ska` WHERE nm_client =?", nbu
);
if (results) {
    inv.push(results);
}
console.log(inv);//this just []}
```